# Error with nested query

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, DeviceName, DeviceTypeId
FROM device
WHERE DeviceTypeId LIKE (SELECT DeviceId FROM net_backupdevice WHERE CustomerId = '1');
```

after execution following error display.

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

This table net_backupdevice return 2 records and I want both record information id, DeviceName, DeviceTypeId stored in device table.

so please help.

Comment: The Sub query Return more the value, try join query instant of sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, DeviceName, DeviceTypeId FROM device WHERE DeviceTypeId IN (select DeviceId from net_backupdevice where CustomerId = '1');
```

Please notice the IN instead of Like

Answer (score 0):

Most simple fix

```
SELECT id, DeviceName, DeviceTypeId 
FROM device 
WHERE DeviceTypeId IN (select DeviceId from net_backupdevice where CustomerId = '1');
```

Probably this is a correct version

```
SELECT id, DeviceName, DeviceTypeId 
FROM device d inner join net_backupdevice nb on d.DeviceTypeId = nb.DeviceId
WHERE nb.CustomerId = 1;
```